# Java JIT - scope of dead code elimination?

Tags: java, jit

I was wondering about the use of the Java JIT compilation.  My understanding is that it should attempt to compile out 'dead code'.  What I am wondering is what is classified as dead code.

for example - say I set a runtime property called debug to false.
If my program has some code to get that property, and then execute methods based on it, I'm wondering what will be classified as dead code.

```
public static final boolean DEBUG

static {
    DEBUG = System.getProperties().containsKey("debug.enabled");
}

public static void logDebug(String msg) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("My Debug Message");
    }
}

public static void main(String args) {
    // 1) Check if DEBUG is true and log if 
    // it is.
    //
    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("My Debug Message");
    }

    // 2) Call a method to perform logging, let it check
    // DEBUG
    //
    logDebug("My Second Debug Message");

}
```

In main, the first if block checks DEBUG.  As it will be false, I would assume JIT would realise this block will never execute, so will compile it out as dead code.

I was wondering, if the same will happen to the method logDebug - will the JVM still enter that method each time, or will it understand nothing ever happens in that method and therefore optimize it out?

Perhaps my understanding of how JIT works is completely wrong ?

Comment: JIT would have it easier if you define DEBUG as final

Comment: Seems like a very specific question that could be JIT-and-options-and-moon-phase-specific... perhaps there is a way to get a particular JIT to explain what it does?

Comment: Thanks yes - DEBUG should be final, my mistake when I was typing that code out.  If there are specific options for JIT to force logDebug to be compiled out I would be interested to know what they are.

Comment: Really, how useful is this?  If the code is never used, then surely, it'll never be executed? Just how big is your binary? (Far more concerning, is the *maintenance* of such code, but this isn't the issue here.)

Comment: It's to allow us to output some diagnostic info when writing code, but have it disabled without performance impact when in production

Answer (score 2):

The JIT doesn't always completely eliminate dead code.

Instead what it does is optimise unlikely cases so it has next to zero cost.  This is because the CPU can perform speculative execution of code past a branch and if this branch is not taken there is only a notional cost. It does this even if a branch is taken only some of the time (i.e. it has to pick one branch as the one likely to be taken)

If for some reason this changes, the code will still behave correctly, if relatively slower.  The JIT can detect that the optimisation assumption it has made have changed and re-optimise the code. In `-XX:+PrintCompilation` you can see it dump a method it previous compiled and re-compile it.

In short, it make dead code have next to no cost.

Comment: In this particular case it should be able to eliminate the dead code. DEBUG is a final static field, and therefor the JIT can assume it will not change; no matter if it is runtime constant and no matter if in theory one could modify a final static field through reflection.